# How to know statistically for sure if respondents result on a likert scale is proofing anything..?

Tags: mean

I have put a question what flow you get from a digital book, compared to paper from 7 (good) to 1 (bad).

I only had 26 respondents, and this is the result:

```
           FLOW digitalt  FLOW papper

Valid                 26           26   
Mean               5.699        5.538   
Std. Deviation     1.063        1.074   
Minimum            2.833        3.167   
Maximum            6.833        7.000
```

i wonder how can i statistically prove that the digital flow wasnt a coincident? can i just say that because the mean was above average that is evidence enough..?

And how can i best present if there is a statistically any difference between digital and paper..?

is there a way i can use the standard deviation to check the significance..?

Comment: You don't really need a test, you can see from the mean and SD that there is no difference, too much overlap.

Comment: great, many thanks..!and can i say for sure flow has arisen when reading digitally, how do i prove it is not a coincidence..?

Comment: Well, you are probably looking for a test. Mann-Whitney test would be a first choice, depending on specifics.

Comment: great, gonna look into that.. So there isnt a way too use the data i have now. If I have 26 respondents responding with a mean of 5,699 on a 1-7 grade scale with std dev 1.063. Cant i say with this data the likelihood that there is flow occuring when reading is quite strong and not a coincidence...?